# run this controller and javascript code in background of my application asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, cron-task

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> getdeviceDATA()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetRandomValue()
        {

            var model = new dummyData();
            var dataString = "";
            var eventData = TwinDeviceController.getdeviceData();
            if (eventData != null)
            {
                dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
                var enqueuedTime = eventData.EnqueuedTimeUtc.ToLocalTime();
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            }
            //Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
            return Json(dataString,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someRootPath = "@Url.Content("~")";
        (function randomGenerator() {


    $.ajax({
        url: someRootPath + 'TestBlob/GetRandomValue',
        success: function (data) {

           // $('#pValue').html(data.someValue);
               $('#alltext').append(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(randomGenerator, 1000);
        }
    });
    })();
</script>
```

Where can I use this script so it easily working in the background. I wanted to use this code to send data from the device to the azure hub automatically when new data get from the device. I will easily manage to upload data in blob azure but here I am stuck that how automatically new data send to blob and call API after a 5-sec time interval.

Comment: How about using Azure automation or Azure webjobs to run a scheduled task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this javascript code in layout of my application

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var someRootPath = "@Url.Content("~")";
        (function randomGenerator() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/.....",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // $('#pValue').html(data.someValue);
        },
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(randomGenerator, 1000);
        }
    });
})();
    });
    </script>
```